# Vite: bundling multiple files into 1 file like Webpack

Tags: webpack, bundle, vite, webpack-4

I'm in the process of converting to Vite v4 from Webpack v4.

Currently in Webpack I have the following:

```js
    entry: entryPoints,
    output: {
        filename: "[name].min.js",
        path: "my/output/dir",
    },
```

where `entryPoints` =

```js
{
    "js/some/filename": [
        "js/some/folder/someName.js",
        "js/some/folder/someOtherName.js",
        "js/some/folder/anotherName.js",
    ],
}
```

In Vite I'm trying to do either:

```js
build: {
    lib: {
        entry: entryPoints,
        fileName: "[name].min.js"
    },
},
```

OR

```js
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        input: entryPoints,
        output: {
            entryFileNames: "[name].min.js",
            dir: "/my/output/dir"
        },
},
```

When I use `input: entryPoints` in `rollupOptions` I get this error:
`The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array`

How do I specify that all 3 files in the `entryPoints` array should be placed in my `outDir` and bundled together as one file in `js/some/filename.min.js`?